# How to pass web request from WAN server to LAN server for apache2 in ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

I've on system having static IP address provided by ISP,I'm able access applications in this system outside the network, now from this system LAN is formed.I want a application running on local sytem(which is visible to WAN system) outside the network, is any idea ?

WAN system is installed with DHCP,DNS services too.

Answer (score 0):

Well if your router does not support simple port translation i.e. any inbound requests on port 80 are forwarded to a local ip on port 80 you could look at haproxy

You have not made it very clear how your network is set up so I am going to assume your WAN system is what holds the internet connection and external IP.

You can in stall haproxy on your WAN system and set up a conditional redirect, e.g. any requests that come in for example-domain.com on port 80 get forwarded to local IP 192.168.1.25 on port 80.

As you have not said what application it is, what protocol it uses and what OS you have running on your WAN and LAN systems it is quite hard to give you any sort of specific answer.

Comment: Sorry just noticed that you did tell use what the software and OS is for both (My Mistake) so haproxy is ideal for the job, it works based on TCP headers, so if it reads that the request if for blah.com and you have a rule for blah.com in your haproxy config it will forward it to your LAN server.